# How can i add python packages in VScode?

Tags: python, package

How can i add python packages in VScode?
I tried with pip install openpyxl but it doesn't find the package.

I searched in google, but can't find the solution.

Comment: What does it mean _it doesn't find the package_? Do you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

I created folders/subfolders and added `__init__.py` to each.